# Thingsboard-local host won't load properly

Tags: postgresql, server, localhost, thingsboard

Whenever I go to my local Thingsboard server in "localhost:8080" of the Windows PC I'm using, I only get a logo saying "EDB POSTGRES" and a message: "Server is up and running."
I've tried putting "net stop thingsboard" and "net start thingsboard" repeatedly, and I've tried restarting the computer but nothing helps!  Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I used 'netstat -ao |find /i "listening"' and 'Taskkill /F /IM [process id found on the chart, last slot by 8080]' to eliminate the localhost and restarted it with 'net start thingsboard'.

EDIT: Got the problem again and this didn't work. It might work for others tough so I'll leave it up.